# Get argument types for function / class constructor

Tags: typescript, types, constructor

I am trying to do something I am not sure is possible in TypeScript: inferring the argument types/return types from a function.

For example:

```
function foo(a: string, b: number) {
  return `${a}, ${b}`;
}

type typeA = <insert magic here> foo; // Somehow, typeA should be string;
type typeB = <insert magic here> foo; // Somehow, typeB should be number;
```

My use case is to try to create a config object that contains constructors and parameters.

For example:

```
interface IConfigObject<T> {
    // Need a way to compute type U based off of T.
    TypeConstructor: new(a: U): T;
    constructorOptions: U;
}

// In an ideal world, could infer all of this from TypeConstructor

class fizz {
    constructor(a: number) {}
}

const configObj : IConfigObj = {
    TypeConstructor: fizz;
    constructorOptions: 13; // This should be fine
}

const configObj2 : IConfigObj = {
    TypeConstructor: fizz;
    constructorOptions: 'buzz'; // Should be a type error, since fizz takes in a number
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With TypeScript 2.8 you can use the new `extends` keyword:

```
type FirstArgument<T> = T extends (arg1: infer U, ...args: any[]) => any ? U : any;
type SecondArgument<T> = T extends (arg1: any, arg2: infer U, ...args: any[]) => any ? U : any;

let arg1: FirstArgument<typeof foo>; // string;
let arg2: SecondArgument<typeof foo>; // number;
let ret: ReturnType<typeof foo>; // string;
```

Comment: Is there any way to extract the argument type from an overloaded function?

Answer (score 187):

Typescript now has the `ConstructorParameters` builtin, similar to the `Parameters` builtin. Make sure you pass the class type, not the instance:

```js
ConstructorParameters<typeof SomeClass>
```

[ConstructorParameter Official Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype)

[Parameters Official Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)

Comment: Works great! If the constructor of SomeClass takes in an object as first argument, the syntax for getting the type of the object would be
`ConstructorParameters<typeof SomeClass>[0]`

Comment: But what about we have a generic param on `SomeClass`? I tried `ConstructorParameters<typeof SomeClass<T>>` but it turns out it's not valid syntax.

Comment: @W.Leto this [appears to work fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7eAnAlsAwuKAeAkgC7wC2AfNAN4BQ00axJAXNEaQNy3TAD2iEhFAFdghHigAUDUizYkAlFS51CACzQQAdNJLQAvPUac6AX2pnqoSDADya1EroQeJeAGVBaRAHMWA9D7G0M6uAHJCJABGqCyIEdEoQbz8giJikiHunj5+2d4ANMEu8OFRMdBxZSiKNHQq6lqZpQn6RWHxqEH1GpqZHgHerX15QWYWhACeAA7w0JjpAApgKGAkMAaYfP5p4ksrrsQoELiTMzwAZnBIqBjY1rh2qqhkZADaAAwAupyWW4TQU2WqwgLHmuyBa1atTaJQ6KBYAEZClxhgMWAByABuYBAQng6PMP2SAnoKTAiGAswMyAA7ldkOgsDhjo9nhJAfsIPJ2EA) from what I can see. Perhaps it's been fixed since you left your comment

Comment: @W.Leto if you're in a `.tsx` file then use this syntax: `ConstructorParameters<typeof SomeClass<T,>>`

Answer (score 17):

Typescript 2.8 added [conditional types with type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)

Typescript 3.0 added [rest-elements-in-tuple-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), so you can get all the arguments in an `Array` type now.

```
type ArgumentsType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

type Func = (a: number, b: string) => boolean;
type Args = ArgumentsType<Func> // type Args = [number, string];
type Ret = ReturnType<Func> // type Ret = boolean;
```

You can use it like this:

```
const func = (...args: Args): Ret => { // type the rest parameters and return type
  const [a, b] = args; // spread the arguments into their names
  console.log(a, b); // use the arguments like normal
  return true;
};

// Above is equivalent to:
const func: Func = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I'll throw in a more direct answer for the use case of extracting the constructor argument types.

```
type GetConstructorArgs<T> = T extends new (...args: infer U) => any ? U : never

class Foo {
    constructor(foo: string, bar: number){
        //
    }
}

type FooConstructorArgs = GetConstructorArgs<typeof Foo> // [string, number]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

```
interface IConfigObject<T, U> {
    TypeConstructor: new(a: U) => T;
    constructorOptions: U;
}

class fizz {
    constructor(a: number) {}
}

function createConfig<U, T>(cls: { new (arg: U): T }, arg: U): IConfigObject<T, U> {
    return {
        TypeConstructor: cls,
        constructorOptions: arg
    }
}

const configObj = createConfig(fizz, 3); // ok
const configObj2 = createConfig(fizz, "str"); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IConfigObject%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TypeConstructor%3A%20new(a%3A%20U)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructorOptions%3A%20U%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20fizz%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(a%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createConfig%3CU%2C%20T%3E(cls%3A%20%7B%20new%20(arg%3A%20U)%3A%20T%20%7D%2C%20arg%3A%20U)%3A%20IConfigObject%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TypeConstructor%3A%20cls%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructorOptions%3A%20arg%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20configObj%20%3D%20createConfig(fizz%2C%203)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0Aconst%20configObj2%20%3D%20createConfig(fizz%2C%20%22str%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

---

#### Edit

You can have an indexed type variable:

```
const configs: { [name: string]: IConfigObject<any, any> } = {
    config1: createConfig(fizz, 3),
    config2: createConfig(fizz, "str"), // error
    config3: createConfig(buzz, "str")
}
```

Comment: This could definitely work. Is there any way to make it work as an index signature? For example:

    const configs : SomeType = {
        config1: {
            TypeConstructor: fizz,
            constructorOptions: 3,
        },
        config2: {
            TypeConstructor: fizz,
            constructorOptions: 'str', // Should throw error
        }
        config3: {
            TypeConstructor: buzz,
            constructorOptions: 'str',
        }
    }

Comment: Sure. Check my revised answer