# TypeScript: how to get the types of the parameters of a callable?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript has `typeof` and `keyof`. I'm looking for something that would get me the type of the parameters of a callable as a tuple. For example,

```
import subject, { ParamA, ParamB, Output } from '.'
interface TestCase {
  input: (typeof subject).parameters // or perhaps `parametersof subject`
  key: keyof Output
  expectedValue: string
}
```

I know I can do `input: [ParamA, ParamB]` and get done with it, but... you know...

Answer (score 3):

Not cleanly, no.  TypeScript currently (as of version 2.5) lacks the sort of [type operators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16392) which would let you cleanly extract a parameter type from a function type.  There is a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) which would let you use `typeof` on arbitrary expressions which would give you a way to get this.  For now, you can do this (only works with two parameters, can be expanded to more if necessary):

```
const params = (false as true) &&
  (null! as <T, U>(f: (p1: T, p2: U, ...rest: any[]) => any) => [T, U])(subject);

interface TestCase {
  input: typeof params
  key: keyof Output
  expectedValue: string
}
```

which fools the type system into extracting the parameter types for `subject` and declaring the `params` constant of that type.  At runtime, `params` will just be `false` which is good because you can't actually make a function return its parameter type at runtime.

It's ugly (a dummy constant litters your code) but it works.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: "Typescript now has the `ConstructorParameters` builtin, similar to the `Parameters` builtin"--see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54523103/62694