# How to get argument types from function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-conditional-types

I may have missed something in the docs, but I can't find any way in typescript to get the types of the parameters in a function.  That is, I've got a function

```
function test(a: string, b: number) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b)
}
```

I want access to the types `string` and `number`, likely as a tuple.

I know I can get the type of the function itself, as `typeof test`, or the return type via `ReturnType<test>`.

When I tried `keyof typeof test`, it returned `never`, which I also couldn't explain.

Other answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481518/get-argument-types-for-function-class-constructor) point to `extends`, but I don't really understand how that works and don't give me an easy way to access the set-of-all-params as a type.

Comment: I am afraid that I do not quite understand: Do you want to get `string` from `a` and `number` from `b`?

Comment: I want to get `[string, number]` or similar (a tuple, perhaps) from applying some sort of operation to the function `test`

Answer (score 549, accepted):

Typescript now comes with a [predefined `Parameters<F>` type alias in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1474) which is almost the same as `ArgumentTypes<>` below, so you can just use that instead of creating your own type alias.

```
type TestParams = Parameters<(a: string, b: number) => void> // [string, number]
```

Then to get for example the second parameter's type you can use the numeric indexing operator:

```
type SecondParam = TestParams[1] // number
```

Original answer:

---

Yes, now that TypeScript 3.0 has introduced [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897), you can create a conditional type to do this:

```
type ArgumentTypes<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;
```

Let's see if it works:

```
type TestArguments = ArgumentTypes<typeof test>; // [string, number]
```

Looks good.  Note that these beefed-up tuples also capture things like optional parameters and rest parameters:

```
declare function optionalParams(a: string, b?: number, c?: boolean): void;
type OptionalParamsArgs = ArgumentTypes<typeof optionalParams>; 
// [string, (number | undefined)?, (boolean | undefined)?]

declare function restParams(a: string, b: number, ...c: boolean[]): void;
type RestParamsArgs = ArgumentTypes<typeof restParams>;
// [string, number, ...boolean[]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz. It appears this functionality is now available in TypeScript itself as `Parameters`.

Comment: what does `infer` keyword mean?

Comment: See [Type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types)

Comment: is it possible to use parameter types of a function to define parameter types of another function when parameters are unknown (...args: any[])?

Comment: nevermind, found it. for anyone wondering, you can do like: `(...args: Parameters<typeof anotherFunction>) => ....`

Comment: @ErfanAzary that didn't work for me. I did this

```ts
(...[args]: Parameters<typeof anotherFunction>) => ....
```

Comment: @o-az you have extra brackets around `args`

Comment: @ErfanAzary that's on purpose

Comment: @o-az so what's not working for you exactly? by using `...[args]`, type of `args` will be type of first argument of `anotherFunction` which doesn't seem to be the purpose of naming it `args`, if you want `args` to be list (array) of all arguments, then it should be like `...args`. Please explain a little more specific when you say not working to see whats the problem

Comment: What if the function is inside a variable and refers to a method inside an object?

Comment: I can't really answer followup questions in comments on answers to old questions, especially not without a [mre] of the issue. If you can't find an existing answer you might want to post a new question (and then you'll get more eyes on it than just people who follow comments on old questions).