# Typescript React: Conditionally optional props based on the type of another prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to type a fetcher component API that I'm working on. The idea is quite simple, you give it a `fetcher` (promise returning function) and a `params` array (representing the positional arguments) as props, and it will provide the results to a render prop.

```
type FunctionType<A extends any[] = any[], R = any> = (...args: A) => R

type Arguments<T> = T extends FunctionType<infer R, any> ? R : never

type PromiseReturnType<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<infer R>
  ? R
  : never

type ChildrenProps<F> = {
  data: PromiseReturnType<F>
}

type Props<F> = {
  fetcher: F
  params: Arguments<F>
  children: (props: ChildrenProps<F>) => React.ReactNode
}

class Fetch<F> extends React.Component<Props<F>> {
  render() {
    return null
  }
}

const usage = (
  <div>
    <Fetch fetcher={getUser} params={[{ id: 5 }]}>
      {({ data: user }) => (
        <div>
          {user.name} {user.email}
        </div>
      )}
    </Fetch>

    <Fetch fetcher={getCurrentUser} params={[]}> // <-- Redundant since getCurrentUser doesn't have any params
      {({ data: user }) => (
        <div>
          {user.name} {user.email}
        </div>
      )}
    </Fetch>
  </div>
)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to say that if the fetcher function does not take arguments, the `params` prop should not be present or even optional?

I tried to modify the props as follows, only adding the `params` field if `fetcher` has > 0 arguments

```
type Props<F> = {
  fetcher: F
  children: (props: ChildrenProps<F>) => React.ReactNode
} & (Arguments<F> extends [] // no arguments
  ? {} // no params
  : { // same as before
      params: Arguments<F>
    })
```

Which actually works, however now in the render prop the `data` field is no longer typed correctly.

```
<Fetch fetcher={getUser} params={[{ id: 5 }]}>
  {({ data: user }) => ( // data: any, yet user: never...?
    <div>
      {user.name} {user.email} // name / email does not exist on type never
    </div>
  )}
</Fetch>
```

I'm not sure why this is the case.

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the modified `Props` is actually working from based on the following examples

```
type PropsWithGetUser = Props<typeof getUser>
type PropsWithGetCurrentUser = Props<typeof getCurrentUser>

const test1: PropsWithGetCurrentUser["children"] = input => input.data.email
const test2: PropsWithGetUser["children"] = input => input.data.email
```

that work without errors.

The resulting types of `PropsWithGetUser` and `PropsWithGetCurrentUser` are also inferred as the following which seems correct.

```
type PropsWithGetCurrentUser = {
  fetcher: () => Promise<User>
  children: (props: ChildrenProps<() => Promise<User>>) => React.ReactNode
}

type PropsWithGetUser = {
  fetcher: (
    {
      id,
    }: {
      id: number
    },
  ) => Promise<User>
  children: (
    props: ChildrenProps<
      (
        {
          id,
        }: {
          id: number
        },
      ) => Promise<User>
    >,
  ) => React.ReactNode
} & {
  params: [
    {
      id: number
    }
  ]
}
```

Could the issue have something to do with the way I am using this with React?

Comment: Yeah, your update works because the type is already resolved, the problem is when you ask the compiler to infer at the same time ..

Comment: Someone else might prove me wrong (and I hope they do) but I don't think you will be able to do better then specifying the function type explicitly ie: `<Fetch<typeof getUser> fetcher={getUser} params={[{ id: 5 }]}>`

Comment: Thanks, Meligy's answer seems to get around this by the use of another type parameter. Do you know if there is a fundamental reason why my approach can't work? Or is it just part of the way typescript is implemented?

Comment: No that seems fine, jealous I didn't think about it myself :-P

Answer (score 4):

This is possible in TypeScript 3.0.

To answer the question, I used `ArgumentTypes<F>` from
[this answer to: How to get argument types from function in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851844/146656).

Here's how:
[Demo on TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20ArgumentTypes%3CF%20extends%20Function%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20F%20extends%20(...args%3A%20infer%20A)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%20A%20%3A%20never%3B%0A%0Atype%20Props%3CF%20extends%20Function%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Params%20%3D%20ArgumentTypes%3CF%3E%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20Params%20extends%20%7B%20length%3A%200%20%7D%20%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fetcher%3A%20F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fetcher%3A%20F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params%3A%20Params%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20runTest%3CF%20extends%20Function%3E(props%3A%20Props%3CF%3E)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Afunction%20test0()%20%7B%20%7D%0Afunction%20test1(one%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0ArunTest(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fetcher%3A%20test0%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%2C%20params%3A%20%5B%5D%20%2F%2F%20Error%0A%7D)%3B%0ArunTest(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fetcher%3A%20test1%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Comment%20it%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20or%20replace%20it%20with%20invalid%20args%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20and%20see%20error%0A%20%20%20%20%2C%20params%3A%20%5B1%5D%0A%7D)%3B)

```
type ArgumentTypes<F extends Function> =
    F extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

type Props<F extends Function,
    Params = ArgumentTypes<F>> =
    Params extends { length: 0 } ?
    {
        fetcher: F;
    } : {
        fetcher: F;
        params: Params
    };

function runTest<F extends Function>(props: Props<F>) { }

function test0() { }
function test1(one: number) { }

runTest({
    fetcher: test0
    // , params: [] // Error
});
runTest({
    fetcher: test1
    // Comment it, 
    //  or replace it with invalid args
    //  and see error
    , params: [1]
});
```

Comment: This works great. The use of the extra type parameter `Params = ArgumentTypes<F>` seems to do the trick by resolving the arguments type in advance I'm guessing? Didn't occur to me to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Resolving argument types is relatively easy, by itself, but the problem was that when you use the same type for another thing, in this case `params`, it uses this type of whatever that's set to in usage instead, and since the default value for the args is `any[]`, a lot of things fit to it. The real magic is in the conditional check `Params extends { length: 0 }`

Comment: Actually I found that the types of `data` within the render prop is still not resolving correctly. I thought it was working because I was writing `<Fetch<typeof getUser> fetcher={getUser} params={[{ id: 5 }]}>` as suggested by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir. The part with params being optional when fetchers has no arguments was actually already working in my example.

Comment: This is very cool, but now the question is how to extend it to 3 or more conditional types? :)