# How do I define a TypeScript type for React props where prop B is only accepted if prop A is passed to a component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My component `Text` has 2 props: `isHideable: boolean` and `hidden: boolean`. How do I permit `Hidden` as a prop only when `isHideable` is `true`?

Currently, I'm accepting both `isHideable` and `hidden` which is less than ideal:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  isHideable?: boolean;
  hidden?: boolean;
};

const Text: React.FC = ({ children, isHideable, hidden }: Props) => {
  if (!isHideable && hidden) {
    console.log("No, you can’t do that.")
  }

  return (
    <span isHideable={isHideable} hidden={hidden}>
      {children}
    </span>
  );
};
```

#### Partial solution

I feel [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771626/typescript-react-conditionally-optional-props-based-on-the-type-of-another-prop) might be the answer alongside the use of TypeScript’s [`Parameters<F>` type alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851677/how-to-get-argument-types-from-function-in-typescript/51851844#51851844), but I’m having trouble piecing things together.

#### Why don’t I want to solve this using union types?

I believe this can be solved using union types doing this:

```
type IsHideable = {
  isHideable: true;
  hidden?: boolean;
}

type IsNotHideable = {
  isHideable?: false;
}

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
} & (IsHideable | IsNotHideable);
```

But I’d like to avoid this because if the conditions to accept props get more complex, unions will be messier (e.g. If I want prop D’s acceptance to depend on prop C, prop C to depend on prop B, prop B to prop A).

Answer (score 2):

I think union is the only proper way to express your intention. In regards to the messiness you worry about, you can handle it with union & union operation to produce union of intersection type, see below:

```js
type IHideability = { isHideable?: false } | { isHideable: true, hidden?: boolean }

type IEditability = { isEditable?: false } | { isEditable: true, readonly?: boolean }

type Props = IHideability & IEditability & { children: React.ReactNode };
```

Comment: The "correct' way might be [functional overloading](https://github.com/sw-yx/react-typescript-cheatsheet/issues/110) - haven't heard of it before. Looking into it.

Comment: @StephenKoo both discriminated union and function overload address your problem, but in different way. For your case, I think discriminated union is better.

Comment: @StephenKoo Funtion overload focuses more on the outside, it report error if you pass wrong param to the function. But inside the function body, when you define the function, you don't have useful code suggestion and type checking.

Comment: This is interesting topic, pros and cons of discriminated union vs function overload when applied to function params. It needs a whole article to explore all details.