# How to correctly type a function wrapper using ...rest ...spread to pick up overloads?

Tags: typescript, axios, overloading

I am trying to make a wrapper for `axios` function from the [Axios npm package](https://github.com/axios/axios).

The function can be called as either

```
axios(config: AxiosRequestConfig) 
// When URL is contained inside config
```

or

```
axios(
   url: string,
   config: AxiosRequestConfig, 
)
// when it's not
```

my simple wrapper looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

type AxiosArguments = Parameters<typeof axios>
const axiosWrapper = async (...args: AxiosArguments) => await axios(...args)

export default axiosWrapper
```

however this way TypeScript doesn't pick up the overload - when I try

```
export const fetchSomething = () => wrappedAxios({
    url: '/url/to/something/',
    method: 'get',
})
```

I get an error:

> Error:(5, 60) TS2345: Argument of type '{ url: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

How do I make it work? I would prefer to learn to do this in general rather than just import the correct type form Axios.

Comment: Look at this to see how the Parameters type alias works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851677/how-to-get-argument-types-from-function-in-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
async function axiosWrapper(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosReturnValue>;
async function axiosWrapper(url: string, config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosReturnValue>;
async function axiosWrapper(urlOrConfig: string|AxiosRequestConfig, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosReturnValue> {
    if (typeof urlOrConfig === "string") {
        // The version with a URL
        return /*...*/;
    }
    // The version without
    return /*...*/;
}
```

`AxiosReturnValue` is a placeholder in the above. You'd want it to be whatever you're returning from your wrapper. If you're returning what `axios` is returning, use the same return type it uses. (If that's a `Promise` type, use it directly, not within `Promise`. So for instance, if `axios`'s return type is `Promise<Something>`, use `Promise<Something>`, not `Promise<Promise<Something>>`.)

It [looks like](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts) axios uses a generic return type, `AxiosResponse<T>`. If so, then:

```
async function axiosWrapper<T>(config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
async function axiosWrapper<T>(url: string, config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
async function axiosWrapper<T>(urlOrConfig: string|AxiosRequestConfig, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> {
    if (typeof urlOrConfig === "string") {
        // The version with a URL
        return /*...*/;
    }
    // The version without
    return /*...*/;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, getting AxiosReturnValue by `type AxiosReturnValue = ReturnType<typeof axios>`, but I get *Error:(9, 3) TS2739: Type AxiosResponse<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosPromise<any>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally*-.

Comment: When I do `type AxiosReturnValue = Axios.AxiosPromise
`, I get *Error:(4, 58) TS1055: Type 'AxiosPromise' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.*

Comment: @MichalKurz - I've updated the answer, I should have mentioned that `AxiosReturnType` was a placeholder. See the new paragraph about return types and the following bit about `AxiosResponse<T>`.