# How to get a function parameter types

Tags: typescript, parameters, reflect, reflect-metadata

I am able to get a method's parameter types easily with *ReflectAPI*:

```
Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, propertyKey);
```

but, when I try to get a function's parameter types it is always returning undefined. I have tried to do with these example functions:

```
const foo = (bar: Bar) => void 0;

function foo(bar: Bar) {}
export function foo(bar: Bar) {}
```

And also I read that TypeScript only emits metadata when you decorate a class and method. So, how can I get a function's metadata?

Answer (score -2):

If you're talking about getting function parameter type at **run-time**, it's impossible at the time of writing since TypeScript do not support this due to [type erasure](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) during transpilation. In other words, type information are thrown away once TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript.

However, if you're talking about getting function parameter's type **compile-time**, then it's possible with [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types). The answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851844/6587634

Comment: This is incorrect. It's possible to get some types at run-time with decorators, Reflection API and enabling certain flags in the tsconfig. A popular framework which uses this all the time is Angular.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović do you mind providing an example?

Comment: The OP's post has a code snippet for `design:paramtypes`. Search for “reflect-metadata” on this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: If that is correct, I think you should be able to provide a working example for the OP?