# Generic React Component with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

Not sure if the name "generic component" is correct, nonetheless I cannot come up with the right way of doing that.

The idea is to have a component that accepts `tag` as a prop, and that `tag` can be either a string (tag name) or a component constructor (FC, class component).

Here's the example code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <GeneicComponent tag="span">
      {/* some content here */}
    </GeneicComponent>
  )
}

export const MyComponent2 = () => {
  return (
    <GeneicComponent tag={SomeCustomComponent} {/* SomeCustomComponents props */}>
      {/* some content here */}
    </GeneicComponent>
  )
}
```

This approach works just fine until you're trying to pass extra props. GenericComponent must infer those props from `tag` and extend its own props with inferred ones, yet I have no idea now how to do that. Another problem is to infer props when the tag name passed as a string. I'm pretty sure it's something related to `JSX.IntrinsicElements` but had no luck experimenting with that.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component is just a function and it's props are just the first parameter to that function. One can derive the [parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851677/how-to-get-argument-types-from-function-in-typescript) from a function type:

```
 function GenericComponent<T extends Function>(
   props: { tag: T } & { [key in keyof Parameters<T>[0]]: Parameters<T>[0][key] }
 ) { /*...*/ }
```