# How to create function that will return a function with type inference using generics in typescript

Tags: typescript

Let say i want to run generateFunction() that will return this function:

```js
// This is the returned function
const suppliedFunction = <T>(args: T) => {
    return true;
}; // This is the returned function

// so I can use it like this
suppliedFunction({ prop: "value" });
```

I decided to create the generatorFunction like this:

```js
// Function generator, returning supplied function from the parameter
// The supplied function should returning a boolean
function generateFunction(fn: <T>(args: T) => boolean) {
    return fn;
}

// But this code gives me an error
// Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'unknown'
const resultFunction = generateFunction(({ prop }) => {
    return true;
});
```

My goal is i could use resultFunction with type inference based on generated function (not by explicitly writing the type

```js
// This should gives an error
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ prop: any; }'
resultFunction('text');

// This should be OK
resultFunction({ prop: "winter" });
```

How do we really implement this generics for my case? Thakks in advance.

Comment: Can you say _why_ the generator takes a function and returns it? Is it "decorating" it (wrapping it with extra work, such as logging)?

Comment: The issue is simple: in the code that gives an error, you have not provided any information that TS can use to infer the type of the function.

Comment: Either you need to pass in an already-typed function, explicitly specify the type parameter, or use a default.

Comment: You shouldn't write `({prop})=>true` without annotating the arg type like `({prop}:{prop:any})=>true`. Otherwise the compiler will not know what that type should be and will fail to infer it from context.  But once you do properly give the callback type a function you should be able to do what you want by giving `T` the propert scope.  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wvx93N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining further; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Darryl Noakes kinda, it will become a custom react hook, so the return value should be a decorated function but with same parameters from the supplied function.

Comment: jcalz, my assumptions is doesn't we could "destructure" an object as from the parameter function? Just like destructuring props in react. That way would achieve my goal, so the returned function will have "hint" that it should supply an object based the destructured properties in the supplied function parameter

Comment: At best you’d get an implicit `any` in that case, but that won’t work for inference.  I’m confused whether or not you want me to write up an answer. Could you please give me a yes or no so I can know how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: [Check this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8pQN), what i want to achieve, it could dynamically switch between primitive type `(property:string)` or object type `({property:string})`. But i don't want to create separate function like that, i want anonymous function supplied directly to the generator

Comment: I don't have anything more than my first comment. Doing it your way causes the compiler to fail to infer, as the type of `T` depends on the type of callback parameter, which depends on context, but that context isn't available. Without context the compiler will fall back to `{prop: any}` (not `{prop: string}`) but even that is too late for `T` to be inferred. I think I understand what you want, but it's not directly possible. I *thought* you told me to write up an answer but that comment is gone now and you're reiterating stuff I thought we had settled.  How should I proceed?

Comment: I have no problem with allowing implicit "any" type for my project because I'm preparing  a library to decorate a function, so it should be can be used in javascript or typescript project, with implicit or explicitly typed. I just want it to be type hinted, and i found the answer, gonna post the answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i just found what I wanted, after 3 days of solving this, thanks to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) from this [post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851677/how-to-get-argument-types-from-function-in-typescript) i could use custom ArgumentTypes and custom ReturnTypes based on generics. Somehow, using Parameters<> and ReturnType<> utilities from typescript is not working for my project so I decided to use custom utility provided from that answer, then I made this

```js
type Serializables =
    | Function
    | PropertyDescriptor
    | Document
    | Omit<RegExp, "lastIndex">
    | never;

type SerializableParam<Serializable> = Serializable extends Serializables
    ? unknown
    : Serializable;

type SerializableReturnType<Serializable> =
    Serializable extends Serializables | void ? never : Serializable;

type ArgumentTypes<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: infer A) => any
    ? A
    : never;

type ReturnType<F extends Function> = F extends (...args: any) => infer A
    ? A
    : never;

interface SupplierFunction<T, Payload> extends Function {
    (arg0?): Payload extends undefined
        ? never
        : SerializableReturnType<ReturnType<T & Function>>;
    (arg0: SerializableParam<Payload>): SerializableReturnType<
        ReturnType<T & Function>
    >;
    (...arg0: SerializableParam<Payload>[]): Payload extends undefined
        ? never
        : SerializableReturnType<ReturnType<T & Function>>;
}

export default function generateFunction<F>(
    fn: F & SupplierFunction<F, ArgumentTypes<F & Function>[0]>
) {
    return async (payload: ArgumentTypes<F & Function>[0]) => {
        const result: SerializableReturnType<ReturnType<F & Function>> =
            await new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve(fn(payload));
            });
        return await result;
    };
}
```

It works like charm, dynamically and also support manipulating overloading functions so it can be typesafed. If you dont want document object model value passed as parameter and return types from the supplied function to the generator, you can add it to Serializables type to restrict the types.

[Check this out in action](https://tsplay.dev/mpxBzm)