# Typescript infer constructor parameter using conditional types

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Similarlly to how you can infer function parameters with Typescript via type inference:

```
type FunctionProps<T> = T extends (arg1: infer U) => any ? U : never;

const stringFunc: (str: string) => string = (str: string): string => str;

type StringFuncType = FunctionProps<typeof stringFunc>;

const a: StringFuncType = 'a';
```

I want to infer constructor parameters the same way, yet have been unsuccessful so far. Currently my setup looks like this:

```
type ConstructorProps<T> = T extends {
  new (arg1: infer U): T;
} ? U : never;

class Foo { constructor(a: string) {  } }

type FooConstructor = ConstructorProps<typeof Foo>;

// FooConstructor is always never but should be type string.
const a: FooConstructor = 'a'
```

Wasn't sure if this was yet supported in Typescript as the "Advanced Types" section in the TS docs only mention functions and not classes for inference (in regards to parameters).

Anybody else find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I change the `T` to `any` in the return type of the constructor function, the example works:

```
type ConstructorProps<T> = T extends {
  new (arg1: infer U): any;
//                     ^^^
} ? U : never;
```

Remember, `T` is the type of the constructor function, which is not the same as the type of the constructed object.

Comment: This doesn't work. It always infers to never. I'm using typescript v3.5.3.

Please provide a typescript playground example, here is proof that it doesn't work.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=33#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oAqpxhIA8AKgHxQC8UZUEAHsBAgCZJQDeAsAFBQoCCAHcoACgCGqAOYBGAFxQAlggBmEVFACqASiWSEIANz8AvlAD8OqEuEA3Tab79+mADaSknMhBTd+QUFMRBQMbFxxNTg4O3QAWwAjTV1uM3NXPgB6LKgADSgkAAs4dHc2KGShBOTUABpK9GAVTgdNflBIfJpYULQsHHxCYnI-YApjIA

Comment: @Mist Pass `typeof Test` instead of just `Test` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oAqpxhIA8AKgHxQC8UZUEAHsBAgCZJQDeAsAFBQoCCAHcoACgCGqAOYBGAFxQAlggBmEVFACqASiWSEIANz8AvlAD8OqEuEA3Tab79+mADaSknMhBTd+QUFMRBQMbFxxNTg4O3QAWwAjTV1uM3NXPgB6LKgADSgkAAs4dHc2KGShBOTUABpK9GAVTgdNflBIfJpYULQsHHxCYhJOiDg1Oj9gCmMgA

Answer (score 4):

Typescript has a built in utility type for this `ConstructorParameters<Type>`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
    constructor(foo: number, baz: string) {}
}

type FirstConstructorProp<T> = T extends {
  new (first: infer U, ...rest: any[]): any;
} ? U : never;

type F1 = FirstConstructorProp<Test>; // never
type F2 = FirstConstructorProp<typeof Test>; // number

type ConstructorProps<T> = T extends {
  new (...args: infer U): any;
} ? U : never;

type P1 = ConstructorProps<Test>; // never
type P2 = ConstructorProps<typeof Test>; // [number, string]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you don't use curly brackets, see this other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481518/get-argument-types-for-function-class-constructor).

```js
type ConstructorArgs<T> = T extends new(...args: infer U) => any ? U : never;

class Foo {
    constructor(foo: string, bar: number) { }
}

type Bar = ConstructorArgs<typeof Foo> // type Bar = [string, number]
```

See associated [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=39#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oIKoDmSAPACoB8UAvFGVBAB7AQIAmSUCEA7gBQA6IQEMiSAFxQAlggBmEVFACqAShpVhCEFAD8yqJO4A3BQG4AUOcwAbYUk4AxOHCgBvc1E9RMiFBmy4fLLOkn4yhAA0UABGooboALbRCmquUAC+5pnmoJBQAEKiNLC+aFg4+GIkuRBwslBOcBRAA)